# Mistakes/questions in singleton example in book "Cracking the coding interview"?

Tags: c++

On page 259 of the book Cracking the coding interview a templated singleton in C++ is given (I don't want to post all the code in case its copy righted).

The question was to implement a singleton as a template, and with the assumption of a class called Lock make sure its thread safe and exception safe.

The answer is as you might expect for a singleton using the  double locking technique with the Lock object having an acquire()/release() pair.

However the class has no destructor. Is this a mistake or not? If it had a destructor, as the class instance member is static the destructor would only get called at termination of the program, and if the program is terminating any allocated memory would get freed up back to the system anyway. Or would it? Are there instances where this couldn't happen and the singleton not having a destructor therefore leads to a leak?

Secondly the question says make the singleton exception safe. The singleton object is created with a new that isn't caught, and the Lock object is static, therefore is this actually exception safe? If there is no memory for the creation of the singleton then new with throw an exception, but as the Lock object is static there's no way for its release() method to be called and hence its never called?

Comment: If a class does not have a destructor the compiler generates a default one.

Comment: the issue with double locking is that it somehow assumes that the `Lock` is correctly initialized before the first attempt to acquire it. However if you try to acquire it during globals construction it might not be the case (on some compilers)... C++0x solves the issue by requiring that compilers make local static variable initialization thread-safe.

Comment: This book is so full of mistakes... And not just typos.  A lot of solutions are just plain wrong.  And this one is a good example.  Double-checked locking technique is completely bogus since the arrival of  multi core.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd caution that Singleton is widely regarded as an anti-pattern -- something that seems like a good idea to start with, but turns out to be a mistake more often than not.

Second, it's hard to be certain without seeing the code, but my immediate guess is that if you want to make it exception safe, you're probably best wrapping the lock object they provide in an RAII wrapper that releases the lock in its dtor:

```
class real_lock {
    Lock lock;
public:
    real_lock() { lock.acquire(); }
    ~real_lock() { lock.release(); }
};
```

With that, exception safety (at least of the Lock part) is fairly straightforward. OTOH, double-checked locking is pretty much an anti-pattern as well. Pretty much anything you do using it will have at least the potential for a problem on some machines/under some circumstances.

Comment: That's useless.  Mutexes only work when multiple threads acquire the SAME mutex, but this mutex `Lock lock;` is local.

Comment: If real_lock is declared as a stack variable in the singleton's GetInstance() function that would work, and is how I would do it. However in the answer given in the book the lock class is declared as a static class variable, in which case there's no way I can see that the lock can be released in the event of new throwing?

Comment: If double-checked locking is an anti-pattern, how do you implement a thread safe singleton in c++? All c++ books and design pattern books seem to use it.

Comment: @Percy: Jerry's code wouldn't work as a stack variable, because each caller is locking a different mutex, so there'd be no synchronization whatsoever.

Comment: @Percy: Singleton is also an anti-pattern, as Jerry said.

Comment: @Ben, the Singleton object can have a single static mutex.  Each thread has a local RAII *lock* object, but they all use the same mutex.

Comment: @Charles: That's what I've been saying.  But Jerry's code snippet provides no mechanism for association with a shared mutex.  Or are you saying that `Lock::acquire()` and `Lock::release()` internally refer to a static member variable?

Comment: All he mentioned about the lock object were the `acquire` and `release` members, so that's what I included. Without knowing how the rest of the existing class works, it's not really possible to guess about how to do the rest, so I didn't try. It *is* generally possible though. Ben's right that one possible method (though hardly the only one) is to store a reference rather than an actual object.

Answer (score 1):

Exception-safe doesn't mean catching exceptions.  It means using RAII and automatic destructors to ensure that cleanup occurs properly in the presence of an exception.

As for the mutex, the correct way to do that would be to have a static mutex object and an automatic scoped-guard style acquire/release RAII object.  Since the RAII object has automatic storage, it will release the mutex when an exception occurs.

EDIT: This is the correct form for the RAII class

```
class scoped_lock_guard
{
    Lock& m_lock;
public:
    scoped_locK_guard(Lock& lock) : m_lock(lock) { lock.acquire(); }
    ~scoped_lock_guard() { m_lock.release(); }
};
```

The `Lock` object itself has to be shared somehow.

Comment: I know exception safe doesn't mean using catch. My point is the Lock's Release() method cannot be called without one, or unless an RAII is used. Therefore this class is not exception safe because if an exception is thrown there has been a mismatch between the calls to acquire() and release().

Comment: I don't have the code, but like I said, acquire and release should be done from an RAII class which is instantiated as an automatic local.  Of course it needs to be distinct from the mutex itself, which is shared between instances.

Comment: The solution answer is not using an RAII class therefore seems to me the book gives an incorrect answer. I just wanted to check I'm not missing something but it seems not. What about the lack of a destructor in the singleton, are there OSs where not explicitly deleting memory allocated to a static variable will result in a leak?

Comment: RAII is the C++-way of dealing with exception safety, if it isn't in use, then the book is wrong.  The lack of a user-provided destructor doesn't mean that there is no destructor, the compiler will automatically generate one that calls the destructors of class member subobjects and base class subobjects.

Answer (score -1):

In the beginning part of the book the author suggests that she will be writing 'almost all' solutions in Java (page 42).

The Java GC will take care of the cleanup for the static instance.

Comment: Java doesn't have templates, so if this particular example really does use templates, it's not Java.

Comment: And my question says "in C++"

Comment: RTFM .. Palm to the Face! I believe in case of C++ the static allocation will be leaked in the author's solution.